# Magento 2: Custom form image not getting pre-populated on editing the saved data

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom form with an image field. When I fill the form and save the data, the data is getting saved but when i try to edit the same data and save it is asking me to upload the image again. Here is the code below:

vendor/module/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Edit/form.php

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
        ['data' => [
                        'id' => 'edit_form',
                        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                        'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                        'method' => 'post'
                    ]
        ]
    );

    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('wkgrid_');
    if ($model->getEntityId()) {
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('Edit Row Data'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
        );
        $fieldset->addField('entity_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'entity_id']);
    } else {
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('Add Row Data'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
        );
    }

    $fieldset->addField(
        'title',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'title',
            'label' => __('Title'),
            'id' => 'title',
            'title' => __('Title'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
        ]
    );

    $wysiwygConfig = $this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig(['tab_id' => $this->getTabId()]);


    $fieldset->addField(
        'image',
        'image',
        [
            'title' => __('Image'),
            'label' => __('Image'),
            'name' => 'image',
            'class' => '\Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\AbstractElement',
            'note' => 'Allow image type: jpg, jpeg, gif, png',
        ]
    );



    $form->setValues($model->getData());
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

}

Controller /save.php

```
<?php
```

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {

```
$base_media_path = 'webkul/grid/images';
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && strlen($_FILES['image']['name'])) {

try {
$uploader = $this->uploader->create(
['fileId' => 'image']
);
$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
$imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
$uploader->addValidateCallback('image', $imageAdapter, 'validateUploadFile');
$uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
$uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
$mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
$result = $uploader->save(
$mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($base_media_path)
);
$data['image'] = $base_media_path.$result['file'];
} catch (\Exception $e) {
if ($e->getCode() == 0) {
$this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
}
}
} else {
if (isset($data['image']) && isset($data['image']['value'])) {
if (isset($data['image']['delete'])) {
$data['image'] = null;
$data['delete_image'] = true;
} elseif (isset($data['image']['value'])) {
$data['image'] = $data['image']['value'];
} else {
$data['image'] = null;
}
}
}

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    if (!$data) {
        $this->_redirect('grid/grid/addrow');
        return;
    }
    try {
        $rowData = $this->gridFactory->create();
        $data['image'] = $base_media_path.$result['file'];
        // $data['mobile_image']='webkul/grid'.$result['file'];
        $data['mobile_image'] = $base_media_path.$results['file'];
        $rowData->setData($data);
        if (isset($data['id'])) {
            $rowData->setEntityId($data['id']);
        }
        $rowData->save();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Row data has been successfully saved.'));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
    }
    $this->_redirect('grid/grid/index');
}
```

}

Thanks for any suggestions